# How frameworks generate code and add to class path

Tags: android, frameworks

I apologies for my ignorance. Lately I have been working on Android framework. The developer said it is fastest framework built to the date because it does not uses reflection and generates code while building apps. I just want to know how these frameworks generate code and how they include this code in class path. What's there approach ? I want a general concept because I have few ideas and I want to implement them like this.

Comment: Dagger is open source, the easiest way to learn how they do it is to just read their code.

Comment: Dagger uses a [compile-time annotation processor](http://hannesdorfmann.com/annotation-processing/annotationprocessing101).

Comment: thanks. I will  look into it.